# Amazon Cloud Search Experience

Tags: search, elasticsearch, google-search, azure-cognitive-search, amazon-cloudsearch

I might get flagged down by this question.. but still will give it a shot.. 
Since Google Site Search is going out of business and we are not interested in the free version of it - We decided to go with the Amazon Cloud Search option. The challenge though is - it is not straight forward. We have to build a crawler and there are some features that needs to be custom built.

I am trying to see examples where websites have used ACS and worked but i am not able to find anything good.. Have anyone tried using Amazon Cloud search for their Website search. Our website has around 15000 plus pages.

We are .net based solution  - so i am thinking to write a crawler.. extract content on nightly basis and send it to Amazon.  Would it be the right way?

Answer (score 0):

ACS is based on Solr. If your site is under your control, i think the first step is extracting all useful content out and generate them into xml/json files, then use AWS CLI upload these documents to ACS. ACS has REST APIs to let you to get the query result. You need to define indexes before uploading them.